# Material UI Create Multiline Data Table Row

Tags: html-table, material-ui

Currently I'm trying to create a Table using Material UI. What I would like  get to work is a table row, where each `row` has a total `td` of 8. The last `td` in each row, should span over 7 cols within the same row.

I don't know if and how, it's possible to achieve this layout inside one row, or if I have to achieve this layout within two separate rows ?

[image]

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried so far? You need to make it more clear what exactly you need help with.

Comment: Your'e totally right, @John. I edited my question above, I hope my problem stands out more clearly now.

Comment: I totally agree. I didn't downvote btw. I think people are downvoting because the question lacks actual code, and it's not clear if you are using a material-ui front-end framework, or vanilla JavaScript. The tag you used in your question implies that you are using the `Material-UI` framework though. I gave an answer to what I think you are looking for, but please let me know if you meant something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to create the layout you are looking for by introducing `display: flex;` on your `tr`. We also need to use `flex-wrap: wrap;` to make the items wrap (create a new row) if the first row exceeds it's maximum space.

```css
table {
 width:100%
}
tr{
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
tr td {
 flex: 1 0 13%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background: gray;
}

/* Color the last td to better illustrate that it spans the whole row. */
tr td:last-child {
 background: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td>
  <td>d</td>
  <td>e</td>
  <td>f</td>
  <td>g</td>
  <td>h</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>i</td>
  <td>j</td>
  <td>k</td>
  <td>l</td>
  <td>m</td>
  <td>n</td>
  <td>o</td>
  <td>p</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The important part to notice in the snippet I created is that `flex: 1 0 13%;` is a shorthand for:

```
  flex-grow: 1; // take up as much space as possible
  flex-shrink: 0; // don't shrink item to fit in flex container
  flex-basis: 13%; // set the initial main size of the flex item to 13% of available space
```

when each flex item needs to be at least 13% of available space, it should be enough space for 7 `td`s on the first row (7*13 = 91). The remaining 9% on the first row is not enough space for the 8th `td`, so it wraps on a new row. The 8th `td` will take up the remaining available space on a second row because of `flex-grow: 1;`.

Comment: @K.Kröger, could you have a look at my answer and see if it's what you're looking for?

Comment: sorry for my late response. Your answer looks good! This could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of alternative options to the one provided.

Option A : In this example not all TDs are in the same row, but you still may consider old-school approach with colspan.

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">2</td></tr>
```

Options B : Using `DIV` as a row and placing a `TABLE` inside with `table-layout: fixed` to make sure that all cells are aligned.

```
<div class="row">
  <div>Head 1</div>
  <table style="table-layout: fixed">
   <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/artemiusgreat/pen/poeqZOY